# 'SSHClient' object has no attribute 'Popen'

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko, attributeerror

I'm trying to restart my core service through Python. This is my code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='123.456.789.876', username='username', password='password', key_filename='/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa')
print ssh.Popen("service core restart", shell=True, stdout=ssh.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

When I run it I get `AttributeError: 'SSHClient' object has no attribute 'Popen'`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

SSHClient from paramiko does not contain any Popen method. See documentation for the module here: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html

Maybe you want exec_command or invoke_shell?

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly what the error message says: You're trying to call a method (Popen) that doesn't exist in the SSHClient class